# Dashboard lights don’t go dim when headlights are on

Tags: headlight, lexus, dashboard-lights

I noticed sometimes my dashboard lights don’t go dim when I turn on headlights. Do you know why that can happen?

Lexus RX 3500,
2007

Comment: is the brightness on the dash lighting turned all the way up?

Comment: @TigerGuy the brightness is the max possible, but the dimmer is not turned on to the very end position.